# Pytest - how to link a specific setup and teardown functions to a specific test function?

Tags: python, pytest

Similar questions have been asked but none of the answers solved my problem:

I have the following 3 functions:

```
def specific_setup_function():
    print("\n\nsetup_function\n\n")


def specific_teardown_function():
    print("\n\nteardown_function\n\n")


def specific_test():
    print('\n\nTEST\n\n')
```

How do i make pytest execute `specific_test()` right after `specific_setup_function` and right before `specific_teardown_function()`, regardless of how many other functions there are in my test module ?

In this example it will execute in the specified order because these are the only functions but in the more general case i want the previous code to be equivalent to the following, ALWAYS:

```
def test():
    specific_setup_function()
    print('\n\nTEST\n\n')
    specific_teardown_function()
```

So `specific_test` will be linked to  `specific_setup_function` and `specific_teardown_function`.

Is there a way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [fixtures with a finalizer](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code).

```
@pytest.fixture
def specific_fixture(request):
    print("\n\nsetup_function\n\n")
    def fin():
        print("\n\nteardown_function\n\n")
    request.addfinalizer(fin)
    return 6  # You can return a value from a fixture


def specific_test(specific_fixture):
    print('\n\nTEST: %s\n\n' % specific_fixture)
```

Comment: But what if I don't need an output from the fixture function, what if i need it to set up a certain global variable data and not return anything. Then my specific function will access the global variable data set up by the fixture - is that possible ?

Comment: It doesn't have to return anything. But to be honest, it would be better to return the data instead of relying on a global.

Comment: When passing `specific_fixture` to `specific_test` it says that the variable shadows function name - what's the point of passing `specific_fixture` to the `specific_test` function ? `specific_fixture` is only a local variable when inside the function, it won't be recognized as the setup function anyway

Comment: Yes, it's shadowing the name, but ignore that. The point in passing it is to make Pytest use/call the fixture at all. (You could also mark the fixture autouse=True, so it'll be used in all tests.)